# how to make the session to last for more time in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

i need the session_expiration not to expire. Is it possible. Can someone help me please thanks.

in session.php i have as below

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = time()+157680000;
```

and in config.php

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = time()+157680000;
```

my session is getting expired if user is idle for 1hr, i need that session not to be expired.

Answer (score 2):

From the config file comments

> 'sess_expiration'         = the number of SECONDS you want the session to
>   last. by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero
>   for no expiration.

Set it to zero

Comment: Go to browser console on the resources tab if you are using chrome go to cookies and check on your session expires date.

Comment: do we need to change csrf_expire also

Comment: i have searched everywhere it asked to give sess_expiration = 0 for no expiration, but still it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

set,

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

for no expiration for session in codeigniter...

Comment: can we give as $config['sess_expiration'] = 157680000; how much time it will stay

Comment: do we need to change csrf_expire also

Comment: csrf uses sessions, but it has no relation with session expiration.The usage of session with no expiration is not so gud regarding security of the application. if u need such a requirement, save and retrieve values from db instead.